# Devtools icon not showing up in node webkit app - windows 7

Tags: windows-7, node-webkit, devtools

I am building an app using node webkit. In the index.html file I have added the following piece of code to ensure that I get the devtool/setting icon in my node app's toolbar :

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
 var win = gui.Window.get(),
 nativeMenuBar = new gui.Menu({
     type: "menubar"
 });

 // check operating system for the menu
 if (process.platform === "darwin") {
     nativeMenuBar.createMacBuiltin("Your App Name");
 }

 // actually assign menu to window
 win.menu = nativeMenuBar;
```

..while with the above code I am able to bring up the devtools/setting icon in mac as well as in linux-ubuntu, the same is not working for win 7 and no settings/devtools icon is appearing when the same app is opened in win 7.

Any fix which will make sure that the devtool icon appears in the toolbar of my node app irrespective of the OS(mac,win or linux)?